# Is it necessary to use a standalone jetty install for using the php pecl solr extension?

Tags: php, solr, jetty, pecl

I am currently just running the "start.jar" in the "example" folder of the solr folder.
While trying to contact solr using the pecl solr extension from PHP, i am getting exceptions in the "php_solr_client.c" file in the extension installation.
I am using SOLR 3.1,
I believe the config is correct.. "hostname" - localhost, port - 8983, path - '/solr/'

I can access solr admin at "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/"

What i'm worried about is that my machine doesn't list 8983 as an open port. Isn't this weird. ?
This is my connection config..

```
<?php
$options = array
(
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'port'     => 8983,
 'path'     => '/solr/'
 );

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$doc = new SolrInputDocument();

$doc->addField('id', 334455);
var_dump($doc->toArray());
try{
$pingresponse   = $client->ping();
$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);
}
catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getInternalInfo());
}
//print_r($updateResponse->getResponse());
?>
```

This is the output i get.

```
array (size=3)
  'document_boost' => float 0
  'field_count' => int 1
  'fields' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(SolrDocumentField)[3]
          public 'name' => string 'id' (length=2)
          public 'boost' => float 0
          public 'values' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...

( ! ) Warning: SolrClient::ping(): in /var/www/html/simple/new.php on line 16
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  234560  {main}( )   ../new.php:0
2   0.0005  239096  SolrClient->ping( ) ../new.php:16

array (size=3)
  'sourceline' => int 1704
  'sourcefile' => string '/builddir/build/BUILD/php-pecl-solr-1.0.2/solr-1.0.2/php_solr_client.c' (length=70)
  'zif_name' => string 'zim_SolrClient_ping' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SolrClient` doesn't care where your Solr installation lives or what serves it up.  You can define the connection parameters [in the constructor](http://php.net/solrclient.construct).

If you are having trouble connecting, check that the parameters you're using for the thing hosting Solr, be it Jetty or a baked potato, match up with the parameters you're passing to the constructor.

Comment: If i can access the solr "Welcome Page" at "http://localhost:8983/solr/", what should be my 'path' and 'hostname' ? and do i need to define all parameters which are necessary in the array.. ?

Comment: Please [read about the components in URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), then you will understand what the individual parts of `http://localhost:8983/solr/` are called.  This is basic internet knowledge that you should already have.

Comment: i'm aware of that, what i am confused about is that do i have to direct the extension to the home directory of solr. ?
Things are configured as per this, but it is not working.

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are using to connect and give the full and exact error message -- *copy and paste*.  Don't summarize, don't shorten.

Comment: How about dumping the actual *Exception*?